# How to instruct Google to crawl old, non-linked pages?

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap

I am working on a website for a client who wants to launch with at least 2,000 articles, where in terms of links not all 2,000 articles will of course be available on the homepage or elsewhere.

But, my client wants Google to of course know about these old articles because of their unique content.

I suggested paging but the client is reluctant to use it.

I was therefore thinking of submitting two sitemaps via Google Webmaster Tools, the "normal" one with the last 50 articles and a second one, with only the old articles having no direct link on the website, making sure to keep in the 50,000 URLs, 10MB limit.

Is this the only way? And if yes, do I remove the old sitemap from GWT after all links are crawled or I just leave it there, untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sitemap is the right call for you. Without the sitemap, the crawler will not know that those pages exist.

Even if you remove the sitemap from GWT, the pages will remain in index. But since those pages are not linked from anywhere, it is highly unlikely that Google will index those pages again. Removing the sitemap will ensure that the 40 new pages that you submitted via sitemap 2 will be indexed more often. If that is what your are attaining to do, then you are on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rana! So just to confirm, after I see that the old links have been indexed and I remove the old sitemap from GWT, if in Google I search for "part of old news article" site:www.mydomain.com, I will continue to get results, right?

Comment: Yes. Once indexed, they will remain in the index till you file a URL removal request. This has got a frustrating outcome of increasing the 404s in webmaster tools page, when you delete a page.